# How to add a `for=""` and `required=''` attribute to an element?

Tags: javascript, html

How to add a `for=""` and `required=''` attribute to an element with JavaScript like this: `<label for='text'>Something</label>` and  require to  input`<input type="text" required>`?

```
function newFields(){
    var number = document.getElementById("link").value;
    var container = document.getElementById("new");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (i=0;i<number;i++){
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      label.for = "text";
      label.textContent = "Field " + (i + 1);
      input.type = "text";
      input.required = true;
      container.appendChild(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: `label.setAttribute('for', 'text')`

Comment: Why are you creating multiple labels for the same input element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set the `for` attribute or set the `htmlFor` property:

```
label.setAttribute('for', 'text');
label.htmlFor = 'text';
```

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement) description of the `label` element.

Comment: how do I add xml `required='required'`?

Comment: `inputElement.required = true;`

Comment: The `required` attribute belongs on the input, not the label.

Comment: Yes I know,
I tried this, but it adds like this `<input type="text" required>` in xml only works `require="require"`

Comment: What does XML have to do with this? You're creating HTML.

Comment: so it is not possible to add XML `require="require"`?

Comment: `input.setAttribute('required', 'required')`